# ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Tags: oracle

```
create table widep(
 cac NUMBER,
 ddate DATE,
 dtime TIMESTAMP,
 type VARCHAR2,
 amount NUMBER(10,2),
 constraint qwe foreign key(cac) references cust(cac)
)
```

Answer (score 20):

The **complete** error message states `Error at Command`**`Line:5 Column:15`** which is this location:

```
type VARCHAR2,
            ^^^
```

[`VARCHAR2`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1821) requires a size parameter to define the maximum number of characters. Use something like

```
create table widep(
 cac NUMBER,
 ddate DATE,
 dtime TIMESTAMP,
 type VARCHAR2(100),
 amount NUMBER(10,2),
 constraint qwe foreign key(cac) references cust(cac)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mandatory to give a size to VARCHAR2. VARCHAR2 generally takes 4000 bytes(standard) or can take up to 32767 bytes if it is extended.

We have 2 options Byte or Char.

BYTE indicates that the column will have byte length semantics.
CHAR indicates that the column will have character semantics.
*Source: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to use Java for your migrations, this would be the equivalent statement in your up method.

**If you want to create a table**

```
@Override
  public void up() {
    schema.createTable("table_name").addColumn("column_name", DataType.VARCHAR2).precision(9);
  }
```

**If you want to alter a table**

```
@Override
  public void up() {
    schema.alterTable("table_name").addColumn("column_name", DataType.VARCHAR2).precision(9);
  }
```

> DataType.VARCHAR2 is being used here for your reference, however, you can select from a wide range of different types.

The method **precision** will add the column size.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE widep(
cac NUMBER(10,2) not null,
date DATE,
dtime TIMESTAMP,
type VARCHAR2(50),
amount NUMBER(10,2),
CONSTRAINT cac_fk FOREIGN KEY key(cac) REFERENCES cust(cac)
);
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your code, so people can understand your thinking