# SQL Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_TBL
(CustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerName VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
JobPosition VARCHAR, 
CompanyName VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
USState VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
ContactNo BIGINTEGER NOT NULL);
```

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>   Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
>   00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063030/ora-00906-missing-left-parenthesis)

Comment: Why on _earth_ did you label your question with MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: When you start using a technology or tool its a good idea to get a basic understanding of how you 'talk' to it. The basic syntax is something you should be researching as you work. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN01503.

Answer (score 2):

`Biginteger` is not supported in Oracle, use number instead. And you need to use `varchar2(number of char/bytes)` or `varchar(number of char/bytes)`.

Why the error missing left parenthesis?

Because Oracle was expecting `(` after `VARHCHAR` but it was not there.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_TBL (CustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
JobPosition VARCHAR2(20), 
CompanyName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
USState VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
ContactNo NUMBER NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a maximum size for `VARCHAR` fields, e.g: `field_name VARCHAR(40),`